# JQuery Accordion?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an accordion with 3 sections which I dynamically add info to.  I want to set the height of the content box to the content so that there isn't scrolling.  I have tried everything!

Set the accordion:

```
 $(function() {
         $("#mainsection").accordion();
 });
```

HTML:

```
 <section id="mainsection">
        <h3>Description</h3>
        <section>
            <p>
            A Here
            </p>
        </section>
        <h3>B</h3>
        <section>
            <p>
            B Here
            </p>
        </section>
        <h3>C</h3>
        <section>
            <p>
            C
            </p>
        </section>
   </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's this parameter called `heightStyle: "content"` which will fix your problem.

```
$(function() {
    $("#mainsection" ).accordion({
      heightStyle: "content"
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#mainsection").accordion({
        autoHeight: true
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kehlan/kCD35/)